# Fetch a file from a local url with Python requests?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, local-files

I am using Python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library in one method of my application. The body of the method looks like this:

```
def handle_remote_file(url, **kwargs):
    response = requests.get(url, ...)
    buff = StringIO.StringIO()
    buff.write(response.content)
    ...
    return True
```

I'd like to write some unit tests for that method, however, what I want to do is to pass a fake local url such as:

```
class RemoteTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.url = 'file:///tmp/dummy.txt'

    def test_handle_remote_file(self):
        self.assertTrue(handle_remote_file(self.url))
```

When I call **requests.get** with a local url, I got the **KeyError** exception below:

```
requests.get('file:///tmp/dummy.txt')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/poolmanager.pyc in connection_from_host(self, host, port, scheme)
76 
77         # Make a fresh ConnectionPool of the desired type
78         pool_cls = pool_classes_by_scheme[scheme]
79         pool = pool_cls(host, port, **self.connection_pool_kw)
80 

KeyError: 'file'
```

The question is how can I pass a local url to **requests.get**?

PS: I made up the above example. It possibly contains many errors.

Comment: Can you use local pure python web server?

Comment: Why not just use `html = open("/tmp/dummy.txt, 'r').read()`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As @WooParadog explained requests library doesn't know how to handle local files. Although, current version allows to define [transport adapters](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=mount#transport-adapters).

Therefore you can simply define you own adapter which will be able to handle local files, e.g.:

```
from requests_testadapter import Resp
import os

class LocalFileAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def build_response_from_file(self, request):
        file_path = request.url[7:]
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            buff = bytearray(os.path.getsize(file_path))
            file.readinto(buff)
            resp = Resp(buff)
            r = self.build_response(request, resp)

            return r

    def send(self, request, stream=False, timeout=None,
             verify=True, cert=None, proxies=None):

        return self.build_response_from_file(request)

requests_session = requests.session()
requests_session.mount('file://', LocalFileAdapter())
requests_session.get('file://<some_local_path>')
```

I'm using [requests-testadapter](https://github.com/ambv/requests-testadapter) module in the above example.

Comment: Hello, can I do something similar with fastApi? Thanks

Answer (score 26):

Here's a transport adapter I wrote which is more featureful than b1r3k's and has no additional dependencies beyond Requests itself. I haven't tested it exhaustively yet, but what I have tried seems to be bug-free.

```
import requests
import os, sys

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    from urllib import url2pathname
else:
    from urllib.request import url2pathname

class LocalFileAdapter(requests.adapters.BaseAdapter):
    """Protocol Adapter to allow Requests to GET file:// URLs

    @todo: Properly handle non-empty hostname portions.
    """

    @staticmethod
    def _chkpath(method, path):
        """Return an HTTP status for the given filesystem path."""
        if method.lower() in ('put', 'delete'):
            return 501, "Not Implemented"  # TODO
        elif method.lower() not in ('get', 'head'):
            return 405, "Method Not Allowed"
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            return 400, "Path Not A File"
        elif not os.path.isfile(path):
            return 404, "File Not Found"
        elif not os.access(path, os.R_OK):
            return 403, "Access Denied"
        else:
            return 200, "OK"

    def send(self, req, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        """Return the file specified by the given request

        @type req: C{PreparedRequest}
        @todo: Should I bother filling `response.headers` and processing
               If-Modified-Since and friends using `os.stat`?
        """
        path = os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath(url2pathname(req.path_url)))
        response = requests.Response()

        response.status_code, response.reason = self._chkpath(req.method, path)
        if response.status_code == 200 and req.method.lower() != 'head':
            try:
                response.raw = open(path, 'rb')
            except (OSError, IOError) as err:
                response.status_code = 500
                response.reason = str(err)

        if isinstance(req.url, bytes):
            response.url = req.url.decode('utf-8')
        else:
            response.url = req.url

        response.request = req
        response.connection = self

        return response

    def close(self):
        pass
```

(Despite the name, it was completely written before I thought to check Google, so it has nothing to do with b1r3k's.) As with the other answer, follow this with:

```
requests_session = requests.session()
requests_session.mount('file://', LocalFileAdapter())
r = requests_session.get('file:///path/to/your/file')
```

Comment: tx. something is wrong on the line except (OSError, IOError), err:. My replacement was except (OSError, IOError) as err:

Comment: @LennartRolland At the time I made the post, I was only using Requests in Python 2.x. I'll correct my post as soon as I can spare a few minutes to test the changes.

Comment: Good work. However it doesn't work for local URLs like `../foo.bar`. It was however simple to change the send method so it doesn't use `req.path_url()` but instead uses something that strips off the `file://` and keeps the rest.

Comment: @rocky The non-support of relative URLs is intentional. At this layer of the stack, any URL which isn't already absolute is invalid, since anything well-architected that operates at this layer of the stack will lack the context to know how relative URLs are intended to be resolved. (Basically, you're supposed to make them absolute before you feed them to Requests using something like `urlparse.urljoin` (Python 2) or `urllib.parse.urljoin` (Python 3).)

Comment: This method is working quite well for me in python3

Comment: If your application is set up to retrieve files in various encodings, you may need to explicitly set an encoding on the `response` object returned from the `send()` method. I did `response.encoding = 'utf-8'` for example.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way seems using requests-file.

https://github.com/dashea/requests-file (available through PyPI too)

"Requests-File is a transport adapter for use with the Requests Python library to allow local filesystem access via file:// URLs."

This in combination with requests-html is pure magic :)

Comment: Dear future readers, this answer is wonderful and neat. But if you ever find yourself fighting a `Win Errno 32` exception when you want to delete the file, try first to close the file handle by `resp.raw.release_conn()`.

Comment: That solution only works if the file is in local host: https://github.com/dashea/requests-file/blob/master/requests_file.py#L35

Answer (score 10):

[packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/775b6f6f0098ffa9edd3874b1af4b98378377211/requests/packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py#L18) pretty much explains it. Requests doesn't support local url.

```
pool_classes_by_scheme = {                                                        
    'http': HTTPConnectionPool,                                                   
    'https': HTTPSConnectionPool,                                              
}
```

Comment: This isn't a solution, just a justification why it doesn't work. Can you provide a solution?

Answer (score 6):

In a recent project, I've had the same issue. Since requests doesn't support the "file" scheme, I'll patch our code to load the content locally. First, I define a function to replace `requests.get`:

```
def local_get(self, url):
    "Fetch a stream from local files."
    p_url = six.moves.urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    if p_url.scheme != 'file':
        raise ValueError("Expected file scheme")

    filename = six.moves.urllib.request.url2pathname(p_url.path)
    return open(filename, 'rb')
```

Then, somewhere in test setup or decorating the test function, I use `mock.patch` to patch the get function on requests:

```
@mock.patch('requests.get', local_get)
def test_handle_remote_file(self):
    ...
```

This technique is somewhat brittle -- it doesn't help if the underlying code calls `requests.request` or constructs a `Session` and calls that. There may be a way to patch requests at a lower level to support `file:` URLs, but in my initial investigation, there didn't seem to be an obvious hook point, so I went with this simpler approach.

Answer (score 2):

To load a file from a local URL, e.g. an image file you can do this:

```
import urllib
from PIL import Image

Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen('file:///path/to/your/file.png'))
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants the bare minimum you have to do to get this to work, and with no other external dependencies, this is it:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.response import HTTPResponse

class FileAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def send(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = HTTPResponse(body=open(request.url[7:], 'rb'), status=200, preload_content=False)
        return self.build_response(request, resp)

session = requests.Session()
session.mount('file://', FileAdapter())
resp = session.get('file:///path/to/file.ext')
```