# How to parse a html document which has download in my own computer file?

Tags: html, python-3.5

I have written a python program
(from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor) to collect and download html documents from this website
(http://lis.ly.gov.tw/lydbc/lydbkmout?.ebe0C1E000901000000DC001E000000000000100000000C0370003dc5).
When I open the html files on my computer(file:///Users/XXX.html), using requests and BeautifulSoup to parse these htmls. I failed to parse these htmls.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'file:///Users/martinchen/PycharmProjects/legislative%20yuan%20scratching/list_pages/list_page_1.html'
requests = requests.get(url)
lytext = requests.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(lytext, "html.parser")
```

And I get this outcome:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'file:///Users/martinchen/PycharmProjects/legislative%20yuan%20scratching/list_pages/list_page_1.html'
```

How to parse a html document which has download in my own computer file(file:///Users/XXX.html) just like relative links(http://XXX.html)?

Comment: You are using requests to load a local file, which requests does not support. To be able to handle local files with requests, try the anwser provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22989322/1236628

Comment: @gmazlami Thank you! I will try that method later!