# How to parse xml from local disk file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, python-requests

I have a code like this :

```
import requests

user_agent_url = 'http://www.user-agents.org/allagents.xml'
xml_data = requests.get(user_agent_url).content
```

Which will parse a online xml file into `xml_data`. How can I parse it from a local disk file? I tried replacing with path to local disk,but got an error:

```
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)

InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found
```

What has to be done?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509888/how-can-i-send-an-xml-body-using-requests-library

Comment: Get the file content with : https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html request (Get online remote file) and then parse it with https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html (Parse saved local file)

Comment: The API Call and Data Parsing: https://sdbrett.com/BrettsITBlog/2017/03/python-parsing-api-xml-response-data/

Comment: there is no need for remote file..file is in my local system

Comment: Then use :  docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Badri GS.. It worked

Comment: f14282...I got this error : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'

Answer (score 3):

Note that the code you quote does NOT parse the file - it simply puts the XML data into `xml_data`. The equivalent for a local file doesn't need to use `requests` at all: simply write

```
with open("/path/to/XML/file") as f:
    xml_data = f.read()
```

If you are determined to use `requests` then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123929/python-requests-fetch-a-file-from-a-local-url) for how to write a file URL adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file content using open method and then use elementtree module XML function to parse it.

It returns an etree object which you can loop through.

Example

```
Content = open("file.xml").read()
From xml.etree import XML
Etree = XML(Content)
Print Etree.text, Etree.value, Etree.getchildren()
```