# Python- Is it possible to upload a local file to a server

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a program on elastic beanstalk which would be used internally in my office. It is easier to host it rather than run it locally with firewalls.

On the office network, we have a server that holds reports that would be processed in my program. but they are around 12 clicks to access through a file prompt. I have tried using a [Transport Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123929/python-requests-fetch-a-file-from-a-local-url) to no avail. Is there a way to do this using a post request without needing to actually choose the file?

Thanks for the help! (I am new at this)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. Do you know the path of the files?

Comment: Are you looking to SSH the file?

Comment: @CharliePrynn I know the path of the files and they are in uniform folder names so there is no reason for human input.

Comment: @ltd9938 I would prefer not to SSH the file

Comment: @Cooper You can send a POST request from python thats payload is a file. On the server accepting/responding to this request you'd need a program to handle this. Is that possible? You'd also need a program on the local server to send the initial request.

Comment: @CharliePrynn I was could not find a way to send a POST request for the file without using the file dialog box within flask since a file would be a werkzeug file storage class

Comment: If you know path to your file why don't you upload it with curl or similar app? `curl -F ‘data=path/to/local/file’ http://your_server.com`.